# Paypal subscriptions button and details

Tags: database, paypal, subscription

I just started reading on paypal subscriptions etc... I created my PayPal button from their page. The paypal subscribe button is working perfectly, but is their any way how  can I link my registered users with paypal i.e. How can I deactivate their account from my web side so they can't use their account when they cancel their subscription.

Sorry for my bad english, I am very new to paypal and subscriptions can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to build it on your own you might look up this list https://www.paypal.com/ie/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/small-biz-3p-membership-outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allow users to register for my site. After registration their account is created and they get a user level of 1. At this level they are shown a Paypal button to pay for the full subscription. After they pay my ipn will change their user level to 2 and update their info in the data base to paid and the date of payment.